# How are system calls from man 2 invoked?

Tags: linux, gcc, system-calls

By system calls, I mean functions like `man 2 brk`, not the `0x80` interrupt.

If I understand [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57236/77068) correctly, a compiled C program never **DIRECTLY** invokes system calls. It can only invoke library calls, which might be dynamically linked from `glibc`.

However, `man 3 brk` returns `No manual entry for brk in section 3`. So I guess one of the following has to happen for the `brk` to be executed properly:

1. My understanding above is wrong. Programs can invoke system calls without `glibc` support. But how is `brk` linked into the program then?
2. There is indeed a `glibc` wrapper for the system call `brk`. Then which `brk` is included when I `#include <unistd.h>`? The `glibc` one or the system call one? If it is the `glibc` one, why is it not documented in `man 3`? Where can I find a complete list of available library calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most of the system calls with man pages in section 2, the man pages actually describe the C library wrappers. The exceptions are usually mentioned explicitly, like [`gettid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) that @Sergei Kurenkov refer's to in their answer:

> **NOTES** Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using syscall(2).

Similarly with `pivot_root` (which isn't that useful for general applications), `tgkill` (which performs the low-level function of `pthread_kill`). Then there's [`readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readdir.2.html), where the actual system call is somewhat different from the library function:

> **DESCRIPTION** This is not the function you are interested in.  Look at readdir(3)
>          for the POSIX conforming C library interface.  This page documents
>          the bare kernel system call interface, which is superseded by
>          getdents(2).

Note that there has to be some sort of wrapper. Function calls are made using the C calling conventions, which is different from the calling convention of the kernel interface. Usual function calls are made with the `call` assembly instruction (or similar), kernel calls with `syscall` or `int 0x80` (and that's not counting stuff like `gettimeofday` or `getpid` in the `vdso`). The compiler doesn't (need to) know which function calls map to an an actual kernel call.

Even with the "usual" system calls, the C library wrapper acts slightly differently from the bare system call: The system calls return the error codes as varying negative values (if you look at the Linux kernel code, you'll see a lot of returns like `return -EPERM;`). The C library wrapper turns all such return values to -1, and moves the actual error code to `errno`.

Answer (score 2):

> a compiled C program never DIRECTLY invokes system calls.

it is not true. Take a `gettid` as an example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html. It does not have a wrapper so you need in your program write something like (from man: `Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using syscall(2).`):

```
#ifndef WIN32

#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int thread_gettid(void) {
    return static_cast<int>(syscall(SYS_gettid));
}
#else
int thread_gettid(void) {
    return GetCurrentThreadId();
}
#endif
```

> My understanding above is wrong. 
>   Programs can invoke system calls without glibc support.

Indeed, it can. It uses `syscall`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html.

> But how is brk linked into the program then?

Seems like `brk` has got indeed a wrapper in glibc, since there is this line in the man:

```
The return value described above for brk() is the behavior provided 
by the glibc wrapper function for the Linux brk() system call.
```

> If it is the glibc one, why is it not documented in man 3

I think it is because there is `malloc` for memory allocations that has to be used:

> Avoid using brk() and sbrk(): the malloc(3) memory allocation package
>   is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.

Comment: Though it might not be hard to argue that even using `syscall` _does_ involve glibc support, even the manual page says that "syscall()  is  a small library function that invokes the system call whose assembly language interface has the specified number ..."

Comment: If you don't want to use the `syscall()` provided by your libc, you can write your own version in inline assembly.